# How can I optimise COUNT with GROUPBY mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, count, phalcon

I have **5M** records in **eus** table and **121** records in **es** table. I am doing a left join but the **COUNT** query is making my query very slow. How can I optimize this?

```
public static function getAllActiveEvaluationSymptomsWithNameForDataTable(){
    $queryBuilder = new Builder();

    $queryBuilder
        ->from(array('es' =>  static::class))
        ->leftJoin('EvaluationUserSymptom',  'es.id = eus.eb_evaluation_symptom_id','eus')
        ->columns('es.id, es.title, COUNT(eus.eb_evaluation_symptom_id) AS counts')
        ->groupBy('eus.eb_evaluation_symptom_id')
        ->where('es.is_active = 1');

    return  $queryBuilder;
}
```

**Raw query with Explain:**

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT  es.id AS id, es.title AS title,
        COUNT(eus.eb_evaluation_symptom_id) AS counts,
        eus.date_created AS date_created
    FROM  eb_evaluation_symptom AS es
    LEFT JOIN  eb_evaluation_user_symptom AS eus
           ON es.id = eus.eb_evaluation_symptom_id
    WHERE  es.is_active = 1
    GROUP BY  eus.eb_evaluation_symptom_id;
```

**Output of Explain:**

[image]

**Explain Visual View:**

[image]

This **full table scan** of count is making the problem.

**Note**: All JOINs and necessary columns fields are having proper indexes.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, and should raise an error.

Comment: Your count and group by is weird, SELECT columns should match GROUP BY columns but your are doing GROUP BY on the same column you are doing COUNT.  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @jarlh no it's not invalid. Why do you think it's invalid?

Comment: I don't know about your php but I have ever work with sql so it just my idea. 
Try to count table eus and group by field that use to join with table es then make join (my idea look like count first then join the result to es table)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I need to find each symptom total users counts. i.e how many users have this symptom.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? Newer versions will raise an error, unless in compatibility mode.

Comment: @jarlh mysql 5.7

Comment: You should look into the setting ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY for MySql, most (all?) other RDBMS doesn't have this setting and forces you to do a proper GROUP BY

Comment: Then you will run into trouble when upgrading.

Comment: If you want to count per user then you should group by user. I suggest you read up on aggregate functions and how to use ORDER BY properly and first concentrate on getting the right query for your requirements. For starters you could change your GROUP BY to `groupby('es.id, es.title')`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes I did removed `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from mysql setting. So it means my GROUP BY query is wrong ?

Comment: Show us the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correlated subquery can be a fast method:

```
SELECT es.id, es.title,
      (select count(*)
       from eb_evaluation_user_symptom eus
       where es.id = eus.eb_evaluation_symptom_id
      ) as cnt
FROM eb_evaluation_symptom es  
WHERE es.is_active = 1 ;
```

For performance, you want an index on `eb_evaluation_user_symptom(eb_evaluation_symptom_id)`.

An index on `eb_evaluation_symptom` won't be of much help, because that table is so small.

Comment: `eb_evaluation_symptom_id` is alrady indexed. Your query looks much faster than others.

Comment: just curious how did your query fetched the correct results without using GROUP BY?

Comment: The correlated subquery is an aggregation query . . . but *without* `GROUP BY`.  Such a query aggregates all matching records.  If none match the condition, then the `count()` returns `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to aggregate before the join:

```
SELECT es.id AS id, es.title AS title
  , coalesce(eus.counts, 0) as counts
  , eus.date_created
FROM eb_evaluation_symptom AS es 
LEFT JOIN 
 ( select eb_evaluation_symptom_id  
     , COUNT(*) AS counts
     , min(date_created) AS date_created -- or MAX?
   from eb_evaluation_user_symptom 
   GROUP BY eb_evaluation_symptom_id
 ) AS eus 
ON es.id = eus.eb_evaluation_symptom_id 
WHERE es.is_active = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks this query seems to be faster than my old one. I will have to convert this to phalcon query builder

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these covering index, in these orders?

```
INDEX(eb_evaluation_symptom_id, date_created)
INDEX(is_active, id, title)
```

"Covering" indexes *sometimes* double the speed.