# Select count and counted sum for joined table row at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I have 2 tables **users** and **transactions**

I want to select count user transactions and sum of this transactions.

My query looks like

```
SELECT users.id,
    COUNT(transactions.amount) AS total_transactions,
    SUM(transactions.amount) AS total_amount
FROM 
    users 
LEFT JOIN transactions ON ( (transactions.user_id = users.id) AND (transactions.status=3) ) 
GROUP BY users.id 
HAVING total_transactions = X
```

It doesn't work fine.

My question is how can I use count and sum at the same time?

What should I do?

Here is my full query

Here is my full query:

```
SELECT 
    users.id, users.gender, users.phone, users.email, 
    COUNT( DISTINCT(transactions.id)) AS total_transactions, 
    SUM( transactions.amount) AS total_amount, 
    users.verification_required, user_details.optin_mail_sent, users.last_login, activities.updated_at AS last_activity 
FROM 
    users LEFT JOIN transactions ON ( (transactions.user_id = users.id) AND (transactions.status=3) ) 
LEFT JOIN 
    user_details ON (user_details.user_id = users.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    activities ON (activities.user_id = users.id) 
WHERE (DATE(users.last_login) >= DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AND (DATE(users.last_login) <= DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
    AND (users.gender='female') 
    AND (users.verification_required='1') 
    AND (users.unverified=0) 
    AND (users.active=1) 
    AND (users.gender <> '') 
GROUP BY users.id 
HAVING total_transactions = 3 
ORDER BY activities.updated_at DESC
```

Comment: 'What should I do?' explain what you are trying to do and what you mean by 'It doesn't work fine.' supplying sample data and expected output would be useful.

Comment: See updated description

Comment: Why HAVING total_transactions = 1?

Comment: Either no HAVING or maybe `HAVING total_transactions > 1`. Have a look at this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58990863/2527905

Comment: I want select users only with X transactions

Comment: Then your query should work (although that `select users.*` is unusual with a group by).

Comment: Idea is that I want count and sum same time.
I just copy small part of query from my long query with to many joins and other stuffs.

Comment: And what is the problem? Your query is fine. Post sample data and expected results and explain why it does not work.

Comment: What you have posted works fine, the problem must be in your full query (in other words you have over simplified)

Comment: Yes you are right this query works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7038e8/4
I'll test other parts and I'll update it )

Comment: I update description while I'll test it. Maybe you have quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to aggregate and then join the results to the table `users` and the rest of the tables:

```
SELECT 
  u.id, u.gender, u.phone, u.email, 
  t.total_transactions, 
  t.total_amount, 
  u.verification_required, ud.optin_mail_sent, u.last_login, a.updated_at AS last_activity 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS total_transactions,
  SUM(amount) AS total_amount
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING total_transactions = 3
) AS t ON (t.user_id = u.id) AND (t.status=3) 
LEFT JOIN user_details AS ud ON ud.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN activities AS a ON a.user_id = u.id 
WHERE 
  (DATE(u.last_login) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) 
  AND 
  (DATE(u.last_login) <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
  AND (u.gender='female') 
  AND (u.verification_required='1') 
  AND (u.unverified=0) 
  AND (u.active=1)
ORDER BY a.updated_at DESC
```

I used aliases for the tables to shorten the code and make it more readable.
I also removed the condition `users.gender<>''` since there is already the condition `users.gender='female'`.